# Create wordpress post using PHP script

Tags: php, wordpress

using WordPress 3.0.4. I want to create some posts whose data will come from my another web page. I have created script for that as:

```
<?php
    include'http://mysite/includes/config.php';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo $fetch['name'].'<br />';
    }
?>
```

but how can I use this PHP script to create wp post as their is no option to add PHP script?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I entirely understand what you are looking for, but Wordpress has an XML-RPC api you can use as described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) to create posts.